# Error while executing the following mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

```
select name from movie as d
where d.mov = movie.mov;
```

.
    ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'd.mov in 'where clause'
.
i sure that column mov exist.

but this is true

```
select name from movie as d
where d.mov = mov;
```

Comment: `moive`? Typos don't usually work well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why give the table an alias then compare a column with itself using both the correlated and uncorrelated names?

Comment: why would you alias a table and compare the same column value to itself.  This query if it was working would always return all rows.

Comment: @John - It would eliminate rows where `mov` was `NULL`

Comment: @John Hartsock: actually it will not return all rows if `mov` can contain NULL values.

Comment: @Martin @a_horse with no name well wouldn't it be more readable if you simply use the following where clause "where mov is not null"

Comment: @John - I didn't propose this as a good idiom to replace `IS NOT NULL` I was just pointing out that it wouldn't necessarily return all rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define an alias for a table you **always** have to use that alias.

The first query does not work because once you have defined the alias, that table is now **only** accessible using that alias.

The second query works because leaving out the table/alias prefix is legal as long as the column name is unique.

Comment: Strange error message though. Why does it complain about `d.mov`? Surely `movie.mov` is the problem.

Comment: @Martin: good point. I actually overlooked that detail. But given the fact that the first query already contains one typo, maybe there are more and the error message does not really belong to the query.

Answer (score 0):

"movie" or "moive"? (Concise, accurate, but too short for an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

if

```
select name from moive as d
where d.mov = mov;
```

is true, than I guess you should write

```
select name from moive as d
where d.mov = moive.mov;
```